# Upsert into select PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am trying to combine the INSERT INTO SELECT syntax with the ON CONFLICT method in order to realize an UPSERT, but I get an error when I try to declare the ON CONFLICT. Added bonus since the values I am inserting are coming from different tables, I made a CTE at first to leave all the JOINs out of the actual UPSERT query. Here is what I wrote :

```
WITH upd (a,b,c) AS (
SELECT id_object, field1, table2.id_table2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.field2=table1.field1)
INSERT INTO new_table(id_new, field1, id_table2) 
SELECT a,b,c
FROM upd
ON CONFLICT (id_new) DO UPDATE
SET field1=excluded.b, id_table2=excluded.c 
;
```

With this query I am getting an error that the column excluded does not exists.

For testing purposes, here is an example of datas :

```
CREATE TABLE 
table2 (id_table2 int PRIMARY KEY, 
        field2 varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE
table1 (id_object int PRIMARY KEY, 
        field1 varchar(10), 
        id_table2 int REFERENCES table2(id_table2));

CREATE TABLE
new_table (id_new int PRIMARY KEY,
           field1 varchar (10),
           id_table2 int REFERENCES table2(id_table2));

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1,'text1');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2,'text2');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'text1',1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2,'text1',1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3,'text2',2);
```

Could anyone point out what seems wrong in my query ?
Thanks

Comment: What error message do you get? Please click [edit] and add it to your answer.

Comment: @IMSoP Edited. :)

Comment: What is your postgresql version?

Comment: @W.Mann PostgreSQL 9.5, I add that in the post

Comment: With the `EXCLUDED` syntax, you must use the column of the table you want(ed) to `INSERT INTO`, not the columns of the `SELECT`. The correct clause would be `ON CONFLICT (id_new) DO UPDATE SET field1=EXCLUDED.field1, id_table2=EXCLUDED.id_table2`

Comment: @pozs Ok, indeed it seems to work better, but I am now concerned by the integrity of my datas. What happens with the CTE ? Does the UPDATE part properly use the JOINs it contains ? I am having much bigger amount of datas, and joined tables, and it seems it is not being considered. I have in my input datas sometimes few tuples with the same UNIQUE field used for the ON CONFLICT (there shouldn't be duplicates, but there are), so I use a WHERE condition in the CTE, but still get the error saying that a same line cannot be affected a second time.